# Charging your body with magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrons, charge

Will your body charge, if you will hold copper in your hands and rub it against a magnet? will it transfer those electrons into your body if you're standing on insulating surface?

Comment: Do you mean if our bodies gets magnetized ? In that case answer is no,- we are mostly composed from water. Water is diamagnetic. Water molecules will react to magnetic field by forming magnetic dipole, which will very weakly repel external magnet. But as soon as you remove external magnetic field - $H_2O$ molecule magnetic dipole will cease to exists and so this weak repulsion force will disappear. Thus no any long-lasting magnetic effects on our bodies. Also if our bodies would be magnetized easily, then we couldn't go under 7 teslas MRI scans :-)